# Am I correctly referencing chapters which belong to the same book?

Tags: style, technical-writing

Looking for some help on how to reference chapters in a book inside of a booking I'm helping with.

Should I be capitalizing `Chapters 3 and 4` and would referring to chapters simply by capitalized title be the correct way to do so?

> For those who are new to programming, I strongly suggest reading
>   through Chapters 3 and 4 thoroughly before continuing with the rest of
>   this resource as they contain all of the core concepts needed in order
>   to understand some of the higher level concepts presented in Data
>   Structures and Algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chicago style, "chapter" is lowercased, even if it is used as a title. (An example from the Chicago Manual of Style Q&A page: http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/CMS_FAQ/Capitalization/Capitalization10.html)

[APA style](http://www.uwf.edu/edd/internal/documents/apa_faq.htm#chapteref) also suggests lowercasing "chapter."

The [Mayfield Handbook of Technical &  Scientific Writing](http://www.mhhe.com/mayfieldpub/tsw/capitals.htm), on the other hand, recommends capitalizing "references to specific figures, tables, chapters, sections, equations."

So, in short, it varies between different style guides. If the book you're working on isn't following a particular style guide, then it's up to your or the author's preference, as long as you're consistent. (I'd recommend making a note of decisions like this on a style sheet for the book--which could be as simple as a list in a Word document. That can help keep things consistent.)

Answer (score 4):

That's how I'd do it. I'd capitalize it even if I were referring to someone else's book:

> For those who are new to programming, I strongly suggest reading through Chapters 3 and 4. For those who are more advanced but need to brush up on databases, I suggest Robert Foo's *How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love Relational Databases,* Chapters 4 and 7.

Comment: I really would want to know why you capitalize here. You know, capitalization in English is one of the most hilarious things for a German. It always let me think: "Why don't you just capitalize nouns?" ;)

Comment: In this case, *chapter* is a proper name. I would not capitalize it in the sentence "See the third chapter for more." I debated adding to my answer "If the chapter has a name, like *The Part of Tens,* you could refer to it by that instead," but I ultimately decided that there's no point in using the name without the chapter number so you can find it, and if I'm referring to a specific chapter, then the word "chapter" becomes part of the name. Thus: *Chapter X: The Part of Tens.*

Comment: Ok, nitpicking :D - So it would be "reading through Chapter 3 and Chapter 4" but "reading through chapters 3 and 4".

Comment: Hmm. Yes to your first. Your second example could really go either way, depending on context. I would lean towards the capital letter, but depending on the text around it, I could be convinced that lowercase was acceptable.